# Is there a name for the extra measure that they like to put into country songs?

Tags: terminology, musical-forms, pop-music

The song that made me think of this is [Amarillo by Morning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kX_9Go0Z8e4), made popular by George Straight, but it's quite common in a lot of country and pop music.  In the verse at the end of the second 4 measure phrase there is one extra measure where the song sort of collects itself before moving on to the chorus.  I have a friend that I jam with that puts these kind of one measure pauses into like every song we play, so I was wondering if there was a name for this kind of thing so I can know what to call it when he does it.

Comment: Really nice question. Welcome to Music.SE!

Comment: _so I can know what to call it when he does it_ - In your case, I'd call it messing up the arrangement...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an issue of what we call **hypermeter**; specify, we can call it a *hypermetrical extension*. By hypermeter, I mean a metrical structure not at the level of the beat, but at the level of the entire measure.

Try conducting along with ["Amarillo"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kX_9Go0Z8e4); it's in 4/4 time. After you're used to that, try conducting in 4/4 where every beat is the start of a new measure. It's going to feel *really* slow, but that's correct: you're actually conducting a quarter of the speed you just did. Starting at 0:20, for instance, you'll conduct one beat every time the bass guitar changes pitch.

Just as 4/4 is a really common meter, a four-measure hypermeter is also very common. They opening hypermetrical phrase is something like this:

```
1    Amarillo by morn-
2    -ing.
3    Up from San Anton'.
4
```

With this pattern set up, we expect the four-measure hypermeter to continue. But what happens in the second phrase is there's a fifth measure inserted before the start of the next phrase:

```
1    Everything that I've
2    got               is
3    just what I've got on.
4    
5!                  When that

1    sun is high...
```

This fifth measure that you're discussing is the hypermetrical extension. (A less fancy term would just be "phrase extension.")

---

For the opposite of this process, check out ["Every Little Thing She Does is Magic"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aENX1Sf3fgQ) by The Police. Conduct the four-measure hypermeter at the start; your conducting will match the bass guitar pitches. It may even be helpful to count out the slow "1 2 3 4" as you're conducting. You should notice something a little strange around 0:45! Here they actually *shorten* the hypermeter, opting instead for a three-measure hypermetrical phrase.

---

**Edit:** This "Amarillo by Morning" is a bit more interesting than that: when he returns to the "Amarillo by Morning" text at 0:46, he inserts a section with only *three* measures in the hypermeter. This means that, zoomed in, there are two "errors" in the hypermeter: one bit is one measure too long, one is one measure too short. But from a global perspective, it results in a normative 16 measures of hypermeter; clever!

Comment: Good gracious!  There's a name for everything, it seems.   I should warn you that if you mention a 'hypermetrical extension' to most practical musicians he won't have the slightest idea what you're talking about.  Stick to 'that extra bar before the chorus'.

Comment: I don't disagree :-)

Comment: I’ve always understood hypermeter to have a bit of an illusory element inherent in its presentation that you then have to weed through, not the other way around. Conducted at tempo, couldn’t this also be a 4-beat turnaround rather than extension? Also an extension suggests the prolongation of a musical idea rather than of repose? Third, wouldn’t the material in the 5th line be the start of another 4-bar phrase? I haven’t listened to the song but this is my reaction to the question and your answer here.

Comment: Wouldn't shortening a 4-bar to 3 be  "hyp**o**meter" ?  :-)

Comment: @jjmusicnotes It could be a 4-beat turnaround, but (in my understanding of that term) we're just saying the same thing in a different way. Extension does suggest prolongation, but I think the issue of prolongation *of what*; here's it's the prolongation of the hypermeter. And yes, the material in the 5th line is the anacrusis to another 4-bar phrase, but "When that" is definitely outside the boundaries of those new 4 bars.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Here, hyper- = "a level above", not "longer than expected". :)